# JUnit run threads with static variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to run two threads inside JUnit. The following code will be invoked by several JUnit test.

I want to stop both threads when result is not null. What should I do with it? The problem is multiple JUnit test share the same String result object and somehow this code gets blocked by previous test. The problem is when another test invoke this method, the result would assign to null, and previous test would block in while(true) loop.

```
static String result = null;

public static synchronized String remoteClogTailDir(final int maxRetry, String hostName,
        final String identifier, final String remoteClogDirPaths, final String whichKeyValue) {

    result = null;
    final String[] hosts = hostName.split(",");
    if(hosts != null && hosts.length == 2){
        Thread t1 = null;
        Thread t2 = null;
        t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                String resultOfThread = null;
                resultOfThread = remoteClogTailDir(maxRetry, hosts[0].trim(), identifier, null,
                        remoteClogDirPaths, false, whichKeyValue);
                if(result == null && resultOfThread != null){
                    result = resultOfThread;
                }
            }
        });

        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                String resultOfThread = null;
                resultOfThread = remoteClogTailDir(maxRetry, hosts[1].trim(), identifier, null,
                        remoteClogDirPaths, false, whichKeyValue);
                if(result == null && resultOfThread != null){
                    result = resultOfThread;
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        while(true){
            if(result != null){
                t1.interrupt();
                t2.interrupt();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return remoteClogTailDir(maxRetry, hostName, identifier, null,
                remoteClogDirPaths, false, whichKeyValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute several search in parallel, and take the first search which complete. You shouldn't use static properties for that.

You could use a `ExecutorCompletionService` for such tasks:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
try {
   futures.add(ecs.submit(search1));
   futures.add(ecs.submit(search2));

   for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i) {
     String result = ecs.take().get();
     if (result != null) {
       return result;
     }
   }
} finally {
  for (Future<String> f : futures) {
     f.cancel(true);
  }
}
executor.shutdownNow();
```

with search1 or search2 a simple Callable :

```
Callable<String> search1 = new Callable<String() {
  public String call() {
    return remoteClogTailDir(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this one works! Thank you!!!!! You are right about the test cases search the file in two remote servers. If file is found in either server, then two threads would stop and the method would return the file content.

Comment: @YiZhao If I could help you, don't forget to accept this answer ;-)